# PL/SQL function locking up the table + performance

Tags: mysql, performance, plsql

We have written a function that interacts with mysql tables and populates data in the table made in oracle schema, function is on oracle side, but when ever we are trying to execute it mentioning a span of date the function is not only taking enormous time to execute but also creating a lock on the object which is populated.

Please let me know what might be setback Thanks in advance

----function takes in start and end date

```
       create or replace
        FUNCTION F_ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEST(startDate DATE, endDate DATE) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    v_return VARCHAR2(1000) :='';
    trunc_table VARCHAR2(300);
    sql_query VARCHAR2(1000);
    portalvisitid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.PORTAL_VISIT_ID%TYPE;
    sourcesystemid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID%TYPE;
    perspectiveheaderid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.PERSPECTIVE_HEADER_ID%TYPE;
    frameworksectionid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.FRAMEWORK_SECTION_ID%TYPE;
    interactionactionid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.INTERACTION_ACTION_ID%TYPE;
    valuecontextid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.VALUE_CONTEXT_ID%TYPE;
    valuetypeid ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.VALUE_TYPE_ID%TYPE;
    searchnextpage ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.SEARCH_NEXT_PAGE%TYPE;
    action ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER.ACTION_ID%TYPE := GET_ACTION_ID('Created');
    portal_actionid VARCHAR2(1000);
    portal_actionname VARCHAR2(1000);
    portal_actiontype VARCHAR2(1000);
    portal_visit_logtime VARCHAR2(1000);
    source_systemid VARCHAR2(1000);
    referer_domainname VARCHAR2(1000);
    perspective_headerid VARCHAR2(1000);
    valueconid VARCHAR2(1000);
    valuelist VARCHAR2(1000);
    ssotoken VARCHAR2(1000);
    log_actionurl VARCHAR2(1000);
    lastactiontime VARCHAR2(1000);
    result_source NUMBER := 0;
    result_perspective NUMBER := 0;
    result_valuecontext NUMBER := 0;
    result_interactionaction NUMBER:= 0;
    result_frameworksection NUMBER:= 0;
    result_searchnext NUMBER:= 0;
    result_data NUMBER:= 0;
    vallist VARCHAR2(1000);
    dtconid VARCHAR2(1000);
    dtvallist VARCHAR2(1000);
    idactionurl VARCHAR2(1000);
    idactionurlref VARCHAR2(1000);
    prevurl VARCHAR2(1000);
    TYPE usermappingcur  IS REF CURSOR;

    c2 usermappingcur;
    CURSOR c1 is SELECT plv."idvisit" FROM "piwik_log_visit_base"@piwikuat plv WHERE 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(regexp_replace(plv."visit_first_action_time",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(startDate, 'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(regexp_replace(plv."visit_first_action_time",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')  < TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(endDate, 'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') ;
    --plv."idvisit" =28907;
    BEGIN
     -- <<Truncate the ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER (ANALYTICS TABLE) >>
     trunc_table :=    'TRUNCATE TABLE ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE trunc_table;
     OPEN c1;
       LOOP   
         FETCH c1 INTO portalvisitid;
            --exit when no more records found in cursor
            exit when c1%notfound;
           OPEN c2 for 
           SELECT 
            regexp_replace(pla."idaction",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(pla."name",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(pla."type",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            TO_TIMESTAMP(regexp_replace(plva."server_time",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ,
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_v3",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(plv."referer_url",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_k9",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_k1",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')  ,
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_v1",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(plv."custom_var_v3",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            regexp_replace(pla."url_prefix",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') ,
            TO_TIMESTAMP(regexp_replace(plv."visit_last_action_time" ,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_v9",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_k6",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),
            regexp_replace(plva."custom_var_v6",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),
            regexp_replace(plva."idaction_url",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''),
            regexp_replace(plva."idaction_url_ref",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') 
            FROM "piwik_log_link_base"@piwikuat plva, "piwik_log_action_base"@piwikuat pla,"piwik_log_visit_base"@piwikuat plv
            where TO_NUMBER(regexp_replace(plv."idvisit",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')) = TO_NUMBER(regexp_replace(plva."idvisit",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''))
            AND TO_NUMBER(regexp_replace( plva."idaction_name",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')) = To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(pla."idaction",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''))
            AND plva."idvisit" = portalvisitid;
            LOOP
            --<< FETCH DETAILS DETAILS INTO VARIABLES
            FETCH c2 INTO portal_actionid,portal_actionname,portal_actiontype,portal_visit_logtime,source_systemid,referer_domainname,perspective_headerid,
            valueconid,valuelist,ssotoken,log_actionurl,lastactiontime,vallist,dtconid,dtvallist,idactionurl,idactionurlref;
             --exit when no more records found in cursor
             exit when c2%notfound; 
             result_source := 0;
             result_perspective := 0;
             result_valuecontext := 0;
             result_interactionaction := 0;
             result_frameworksection := 0;
             result_searchnext := 0;
             result_data := 0;

             ---RE-INITIALISING VARIABLES FOR AVOIDING DUPLICACY
             perspectiveheaderid := NULL;
             valuecontextid := NULL;
             valuetypeid := NULL;
             interactionactionid := NULL;
             searchnextpage := '';
             frameworksectionid := NULL;
             ----CHECK FOR SOURCE SYSTEM ID
             SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_source FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE type = 'source_system_id' and lower(description) = lower(nvl(source_systemid,''));

             -----PROCESSING FOR SOURCE SYSTEM ID
             IF result_source = 1 THEN
              SELECT ID INTO sourcesystemid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE type = 'source_system_id' and lower(description) = lower(nvl(source_systemid,''));
             ELSE
              sourcesystemid := 1;
             END IF;

             -----PROCESSING FOR PERSPECTIVE HEADER ID
             SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_perspective FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'perspective_header_id' AND LOWER(DESCRIPTION) = LOWER(NVL(perspective_headerid,''));
             IF result_perspective = 1 THEN
             SELECT ID INTO perspectiveheaderid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'perspective_header_id' AND LOWER(DESCRIPTION) = LOWER(NVL(perspective_headerid,''));
             END IF;

             -----PROCESSING VALUE CONTEXT ID
             IF valueconid IS NOT NULL THEN
             SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_valuecontext FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'value_context_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(valueconid)||'%';
             END IF;

             IF result_valuecontext = 1 THEN
              SELECT ID INTO valuecontextid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'value_context_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(valueconid)||'%';
              SELECT  decode(TRIM(TRANSLATE(lower(valuelist),' +.0123456789', ' ')), NULL,1,2) INTO valuetypeid FROM DUAL;
             ELSE
               ------CHECK ON CUSTOM VAR K9 FOR VALUE CONTEXT ID
               IF perspective_headerid IS NOT NULL THEN
               SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_valuecontext FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'value_context_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(perspective_headerid)||'%';
               END IF;

               IF result_valuecontext = 1 THEN
                SELECT ID INTO valuecontextid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'value_context_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(perspective_headerid)||'%';
                valuelist := vallist;
                SELECT  decode(TRIM(TRANSLATE(lower(vallist),' +.0123456789', ' ')), NULL,1,2) INTO valuetypeid FROM DUAL;
                ELSE
                -----CHECK ON DTCONID AND DT VALUE LIST
                IF dtconid IS NOT NULL THEN
                    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_valuecontext FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'value_context_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(dtconid)||'%';
                END IF;
                IF result_valuecontext = 1 THEN
                    SELECT ID INTO valuecontextid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'value_context_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(dtconid)||'%';
                    valuelist := dtvallist;
                    SELECT  decode(TRIM(TRANSLATE(lower(dtvallist),' +.0123456789', ' ')), NULL,1,2) INTO valuetypeid FROM DUAL;
                ELSE
                 --- no data to be inserted as no context id match i.e. value list should also be be null
                 valuelist := null;
                END IF;
              END IF;          
             END IF;


             -------PROCESSING FOR INTERACTION_ID
             IF valueconid IS NOT NULL THEN
                 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_interactionaction FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(valueconid)||'%';
             END IF;    
             IF result_interactionaction = 1 THEN
                SELECT ID INTO interactionactionid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(valueconid)||'%';
             ELSE
              ----APPLYING CHECK FOR SEARCH PAGE
                IF portal_actionname IS NOT NULL THEN
                 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_interactionaction FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(portal_actionname)||'%';
                END IF;
                IF result_interactionaction = 1 THEN
                 --- IF THE ID IS FOUND THEN
                 SELECT ID INTO interactionactionid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(portal_actionname)||'%';
                 ELSE 
                 ----APPLYING CHECKS FOR OTHER VARIABLES WHICH ARE RECORDED IN CUSTOM_VAR_K9
                    IF perspective_headerid IS NOT NULL THEN
                    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_interactionaction FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(perspective_headerid)||'%';
                    END IF;
                    IF result_interactionaction = 1 THEN
                        SELECT ID INTO interactionactionid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(perspective_headerid)||'%';
                    ELSE 
                        ----APPLYING CHECK ON SORT OPERATIONS VIA MY ALERTS / OTHER VARIABLES WHICH ARE BEEN STORED IN CUSTOM_VAR_V1
                        IF valuelist IS NOT NULL THEN
                           SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_interactionaction FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(valuelist)||'%';
                        END IF;
                        IF result_interactionaction = 1 THEN
                          SELECT ID INTO interactionactionid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(valuelist)||'%';
                          ----CHECK FOR CUSTOM_VAR_K6 FOR REST OF THE SCENARIOS
                          ELSE
                            IF dtconid IS NOT NULL THEN
                             SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_interactionaction FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(dtconid)||'%';
                            END IF;
                            IF result_interactionaction = 1 THEN
                              SELECT ID INTO interactionactionid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'interaction_action_id' AND LOWER(TAGS) LIKE '%'||LOWER(dtconid)||'%';
                            END IF;
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
                END IF; 
             END IF;

             -------PROCESSING FOR SEARCH NEXT PAGE  result_searchnext searchnextpage
             IF  idactionurl IS NOT NULL THEN

                SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_data FROM "piwik_log_action_base"@piwikuat pla where 
                To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(pla."idaction",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')) = To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(idactionurl,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''));

                IF result_data > 0  THEN
                    SELECT regexp_replace(pla."name",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') INTO searchnextpage FROM "piwik_log_action_base"@piwikuat pla where 
                    To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(pla."idaction",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')) = To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(idactionurl,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''));
                END IF;

             END IF;

            --- RESETTING THE VARIABLE TO ZERO

            result_data := 0;

            ----PROCESS FRAMEWORK SECTION ID
            IF idactionurlref IS NOT NULL THEN
             SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_data FROM "piwik_log_action_base"@piwikuat pla where 
             To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(pla."idaction",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')) = To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(idactionurlref,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''));
             IF result_data > 0  THEN
                SELECT regexp_replace(pla."name",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','') INTO prevurl FROM "piwik_log_action_base"@piwikuat pla where 
                To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(pla."idaction",'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','')) = To_NUMBER(regexp_replace(idactionurlref,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)',''));
             END IF;
             IF prevurl IS NOT NULL THEN
             select COUNT(*) INTO result_frameworksection FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'framework_section_id' and instr(LOWER(prevurl),lower(tags),1)>0;
             END IF;
             IF result_frameworksection =1 THEN
              SELECT ID INTO frameworksectionid FROM LISTLOOKUP WHERE TYPE = 'framework_section_id' and instr(LOWER(prevurl),lower(tags),1)>0;
             END IF;

            END IF;

 --- inserting data into table          
            INSERT INTO ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEMPER(portal_visit_id,portal_action_id,portal_action_name,portal_action_type,portal_visit_log_time,source_system_id,perspective_header_id,framework_section_id,interaction_action_id,interaction_type_id,value_context_id,value_type_id,value_list,search_next_page,sso_token,log_action_url,last_update_date,action_id,REFERER_DOMAIN_NAME)
            VALUES(portalvisitid,portal_actionid,portal_actionname,portal_actiontype,portal_visit_logtime,sourcesystemid,perspectiveheaderid,frameworksectionid,interactionactionid,null,valuecontextid,valuetypeid,valuelist,searchnextpage,ssotoken,log_actionurl,lastactiontime,action,referer_domainname);

            END LOOP;
           CLOSE c2;        
       END LOOP;
     COMMIT;     
     v_return := 'SUCCESS';
     CLOSE c1;
     RETURN v_return;
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
     v_return := SQLERRM;
     ROLLBACK;
     RETURN v_return;
    END F_ANLY_USR_VIS_LOG_TEST;
    /
```

Comment: All those REGEXP_REPLACE calls in the WHERE clauses of the various SELECT statements will cause a full table scan unless you've got the appropriate function-based indexes defined. I'm guessing you don't have such function-based indexes defined, and thus your queries are scanning the tables in question, performing multiple REGEXP_REPLACE calls on every row, and thus performance stinks and the table gets locked. Perhaps you could define the appropriate function-based indexes on your tables, or get rid of the REGEXP_REPLACE calls in the WHERE clauses?

Comment: Did you run an explain plan?

Comment: Thanks Bob and OldProgrammer-- the program got resolved using function based indexes.